How to create a dynamic index in a data frame based on a catalog?
I have two diferent data frames. The first one is a catalog of diferent requests type and how many request i had at the moment.
data = {'Req Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Req No': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)

   Req Type  Req No
0         A      20
1         B      21
2         C      19
3         D      18

The other one is a data frame of how many new request i have this month.
data2 = {'Req Type': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)

   Req Type
0         A
1         A
2         C
3         B

I need to create a dynamic index in my df2 that can detect what was the last number of each request type and start to sum. Example: The last number of A was "20", so the index to req type "A" is "21", then "22" and that for all my req type.
   Req Type  Index
0         A     21
1         A     22
2         C     20
3         B     22


Why is B's index 12?

Sorry it was my mistake, the Index B need to be 22

What do you mean by "last number of each request type"? There's only one number for each request type in this data.

You can use a dictionary and update it in a single pass:
def get_indices(df1, df2):
    tn = df1.set_index('Req Type')['Req No']
    res = []
    for t in df2['Req Type']:
        tn[t] += 1
        res.append(tn[t])
    return res


print(df2.assign(Index=get_indices(df1, df2)))

Prints:
  Req Type  Index
0        A     21
1        A     22
2        C     20
3        B     22


Thank you!!! Bro that was very useful for me, you are the goat, M10 CR7, The king haha.

@Amaury the other solution is much better

If I understand correctly, you want to merge, then add the groupwise enumeration plus 1.
df2.assign(
    Index=df2.merge(df1)['Req No'] + df2.groupby('Req Type').cumcount() + 1)

  Req Type  Index
0        A     21
1        A     22
2        C     20
3        B     22


Edit: I just noticed "last number of each request type" in the question. It doesn't actually matter for this data so that's probably why I didn't notice it before. If that's significant, replace df1 in the above code with df1.drop_duplicates('Req Type', keep='last')

Here it is another implementation:
data = {'Req Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Req No': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
data2 = {'Req Type': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B']}

def updateIndex(dict1, dict2):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

    # gets max 'Req No' value for each unique 'Req Type' -> df['Req Type'] = max('Req No') for that 'Req Type'
    df1_key_max = {key:max(df1[df1['Req Type']==key]['Req No']) for key in df1['Req Type'].unique()}

    # creates a new list, where the items will be the 'Req No' updated
    req_no = list()
    for req_type in dict2['Req Type']:
        df1_key_max[req_type] += 1
        req_no.append(df1_key_max[req_type])

    # creates new Df with updated values
    data2['Req No'] = req_no
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    return df2
updateIndex(data, data2)

Each step, for better understanding:
-Creates Dict
# gets max 'Req No' value for each unique 'Req Type' -> df['Req Type'] = max('Req No') for that 'Req Type'
df1_key_max = {key:max(df1[df1['Req Type']==key]['Req No']) for key in df1['Req Type'].unique()}
print(df1_key_max)

>>>{'A': 20, 'B': 21, 'C': 19, 'D': 18}

-Creates list with updated Index
# creates a new list, where the items will be the 'Req No' updated
req_no = list()
for req_type in dict2['Req Type']:
    df1_key_max[req_type] += 1
    req_no.append(df1_key_max[req_type])
    print(req_no)

(each iteration of req_no)
>>>[21]
>>>[21, 22]
>>>[21, 22, 20]
>>>[21, 22, 20, 22]

Then, just return the new df.

You're new to Pandas, eh? df1_key_max can be created a lot more easily using Pandas idioms: df1.groupby('Req Type')['Req No'].max()

Why are you creating new dataframes instead of just using the ones provided in the question?

yeah, i'm new. Just trying to help. Sorry
